# Force Gurobi MIP solve to be deterministic

Tags: python-3.x, gurobi, pulp

I am passing a MIP problem to Gurobi using PULP, with no special params other than gap 0.1 and it looks like the solution path is different every solve.  I tried to set a seed, and use that same seed for each run, and that did not help.  It still took a different journey.  I know it's taking a dif path, because I am doing row generation (getting a solution, checking if a constraint is broken, adding if so) and its finding a feasible optimal one run without needing, for example, constraint x - but then the very next run with the exact same input, it breaks constraint x and requires it be added as a row.

To those who think it may be due to the gap of 0.1, maybe so, but CBC solves the same way with the same gap and does not exhibit this behavior.

Any ideas?  Thanks,

Comment: which gurobi solver are you using the cmd line Gurobi_CMD or Gurobi ??

Comment: prob.solve(GUROBI(msg = 1, epgap = 0.1))

Comment: OK this is probably a bug in the Gurobi interface for pulp as Gurobi goes to some lengths to make a deterministic solution. However, any python interface has to be very careful to sort dictionaries of constraints and variables. As otherwise python will return these constraints and variables in different orders, and the solver will give a different answer :-(. Can you please raise an issue (with and example if you can) in https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/issues and I will see if I can fix it.

Comment: Stu,  I have no tried explicit variable and constraint ordering.  I will first try this and then report back to the community if it helped.  If not, I will raise the issue at PULP's github.  Thanks as always.